# Server side pagination is not rendering the table data

Tags: angularjs, spring, mongodb, datatables

I am trying to do pagination from the server side. My project tech stack is MongoDB + Spring + Angular + Angular-datatables.

MongoDB provides very simple method to retrieve the data according to pagination and sorting parameters

URL to fetch the data is pasted here which is a 'POST' request and also would like to send the few other parameters with request body

```
 /myapp/products/filter?pageSize=10&pageNo=1
```

After some googling and going through the jQuery DataTables manual, I found out how to make this in [angular-datatables](https://github.com/l-lin/angular-datatables). Pasted the code below:

```
     vm.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions().withOption('ajax', {
            url : '/myapp-api/products/filter',
            type : 'POST',
            contentType : 'application/json',
            dataType :'json',
            accepts: "application/json",
            headers: {
                Accept: "application/json",
                Authorization : 'Bearer eyJ0eXAiO.eyJpZCI6IjU1OhSbNTdmIoq1Y'
            },
            data:function(d){
                     var pageNo = d.start;
                 var pageSize = d.length;
                     return JSON.stringify( d );
            },
            success:function(response){
                console.log(" ajax > post > success > response > ", response);
                var page = {
                    "draw":1,
                    "data" : response.list,
                    "recordsTotal" :response.list.length,
                    "recordsFiltered" :response.list.length
                };
                return page;
            }
        })
        .withDataProp('data')
        .withOption('processing', true)
        .withOption('serverSide', true)
        .withPaginationType('full_numbers');
```

I am able to receive the response successfully but the datatable is not displaying the data. In the success function callback, returning the data as per the format which is mentioned in datatables web pages.

Along side, I have few more queries:

1. Can I use `$http.post` method to retrieve the data from the server, I understand that datatables has some mechanism which is calling the ajax on each action done in the datatables.
2. The `data: function(){}` gives me the entire datatable column and other details in object format, used `JSON.Stringify(data)` as workaround.

My server side implementation expects the JSON data and I need only few parameters out of it.

Has anyone here has done the implementation using `$http.post` method. when I tried it, It was giving me the error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'aDataSort' of undefined

```
    $scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
     .withOption('ajax', function(data, fnCallback, settings) {
            $http.post('/myapp/products/filter?pageNo=1&pageSize=10', {}).then(function(response) {
                  fnCallback(response);
     });      
    })
    .withDataProp('list')
    .withOption('processing', true)
    .withOption('serverSide', true)
    .withPaginationType('full_numbers');
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the corrected code below.

You're not setting `pageNo` and `pageSize` as URL parameters correctly.

Also according to the manual, `success` method must never be overwritten as it is being used by DataTables internally. Instead you can define a callback with `withDataProp` that will be called when the response is received from the server.

Please note that with server-side processing `draw` parameter value in response has to match `draw` parameter value in the request. I'm using `vm` object to store its value between request and response.

Another thing worth mentioning is that you need to use DataTables version 1.10.6 or later for this code to work.

```
vm.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions().withOption('ajax', {
       url : '/myapp-api/products/filter',
       type : 'POST',
       contentType : 'application/json',
       dataType : 'json',
       accepts: "application/json",
       headers: {
           Accept: "application/json",
           Authorization : 'Bearer eyJ0eXAiO.eyJpZCI6IjU1OhSbNTdmIoq1Y'
       },
       data: function(d, settings){
           var api = new $.fn.dataTable.Api(settings);

           // Update URL
           api.ajax.url(
              '/myapp-api/products/filter?pageNo=' + d.start + '&pageSize=' + d.length
           );

           // Store "draw" parameter
           vm.dtDraw = d.draw;

           return JSON.stringify(d);
       }
   })
   .withDataProp(function(json){
       console.log(" ajax > post > success > response > ", json);

       // Retrieve "draw" parameter
       json.draw = vm.dtDraw;

       json.recordsTotal = json.list.length;
       json.recordsFiltered = json.list.length;

       return json.list;
   })
   .withOption('processing', true)
   .withOption('serverSide', true)
   .withPaginationType('full_numbers');
```

Comment: Thanks. The data is getting displayed. I have one observation,  The below code is not changing the URL and getting settings as undefined value  . Can we access the data parameter by any other way .                                                           var api = new $.fn.dataTable.Api(settings);
api.ajax.url('/myapp-api/products/filter?pageNo=' + d.draw + '&pageSize=' + d.length);

Comment: @Hurix, there is other way but `d.start` and `d.length` should not be undefined if `serverSide: true`. Can you do `console.log(d)` in `data: function(){}` and tell me what properties do you see?

Comment: Still, I am getting the setting value as undefined. Please notice that, I am using angular-datatables as a wrapper to datatables. My data object is here `{
    "draw": 1,
    "columns": [{}],
    "order": [
        {
            "column": 0,
            "dir": "asc"
        }
    ],
    "start": 0,
    "length": 10,
    "search": {
        "value": "",
        "regex": false
    }
}`

Comment: @Hurix, One thing to note is `settings` variable in `data` was added in DataTables 1.10.6. That's why setting the URL doesn't work. You're probably using older version, can you download the latest DataTables 1.10.7 from their site and retest?

Comment: Yup, you are correct. It worked. Once again thanks :)

Comment: @Gyrocode.com, I know this is an old post, but I am unable to get the filtering working, with the same code above, can you please help me?

Comment: @victor, does sorting works but not the filtering? Please explain.

Comment: @Gyrocode.com, no both sorting and filtering are not working; is there something I need to enable?

Comment: @Gyrocode.com, I solved the sorting, now only the filtering. Guess its a matter of time, but would be helpful to know if I am on the right track. I am passing d.order[0].column & d.order[0].dir for column number and order

Comment: @victor, see if it works if you remove `.withOption('serverSide', true)`.

Comment: @Gyrocode.com, thanks for tip, I get an error "Error: d.order is undefined"

Comment: @victor, then you're probably using server-side mode indeed. Can you please start a new question? You don't need to pass `d.order[0].column` manually, DataTables should do it for you. This particular question required JSON encoded data with `JSON.stringify(d)`, I'm not sure whether your service expects JSON-encoded parameters or not.

Comment: @Hurix- I am trying to convert a client side configured DataTables into server side DataTable, and my tech stack is same as yours (MongoDB + Spring + Angular + Angular-datatables). I would really love to know how are you running your queries in MongoDB using the parameters received from DataTables? Also, why do we need to send the start and length parameters from DataTables separately as pageNo and pageSize?